# Newbie Using GridView CellTemplate from C#

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I'm learning how to make a Visual Studio style properties grid. I have a 2 column GridView, currently binding OK to a list of objects with two string members. Good so far. I want the second column to use Text Entry Boxes so I can update those values.
I've looked extensivly online, but can only find XAML examples of this. What I got so far (don't work, only shows non-editable text)...

```
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        View = gv;

        // First Collumn - Name.
        GridViewColumn col = new GridViewColumn();
        col.Header = "Property";
        col.Width = 100;
        col.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Name");
        gv.Columns.Add(col);

        // 2nd Column - Value.
        col = new GridViewColumn();
        col.Header = "Value";
        col.Width = 100;
        col.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("DefaultValue");

        FrameworkElementFactory txt = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        txt.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding()); // sets binding

        // add textbox template
        col.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(string));
        col.CellTemplate.VisualTree = txt;

        gv.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: Yuck, so much code behind, why would you do this? What's wrong with using XAML?

Comment: It may end up as XAML, but I am stubborn and want to learn how to do it in code-behind also. I am re-facing a C++ MFC application, so am forced in some instances to use code more than I would in a 'pure' WPF design.

Comment: XAML markup is really useful, it saves you a lot of work and it is a lot shorter and less prone to errors. Especially when it comes to templates code behind is a *real* pain because you have to work with `FrameworkElementFactories` while in XAML it does not feel any different than declaring a normal control.

Comment: Thanks guys!, I do love using XAML, but I'm new to WPF, so you'll understand my tendancy to 'think in code' first while I get to grips with it.

Comment: "why would you do this? What's wrong with using XAML?" – how about a case when I'm creating columns dynamically, without knowing bindings in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 on the comments on using XAML for this, but that doesn't answer your question.

I suspect the reason the TextBoxes are read-only is because you are bound directly to the string. If WPF let you edit it, where would it store the string? As you know, strings in .NET are immutable.

Try this:

```
class StringContainer
{
     public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now wire it up like this:

```
FrameworkElementFactory txt = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
txt.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("SomeValue")); // sets binding

// add textbox template
col.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(StringContainer));
```

When you bind the data, remember to wrap the editable strings in `StringContainer` objects.

```
myDataRow.DefaultValue = new StringContainer("Some string");
```

Comment: Awesome! Works as needed. NOTE to self: When using CellTemplate, DON'T also use DisplayMemberBinding (seems to override/nullify the CellTemplate).